# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000***

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics

During few days I am seeing a firebase crash analytic issue (given below) in my console. I am surfing a log but didn't get any solution. I am not sure the crush Mocking line-1 and line-2 (inside the self.addTransferOperation() function). If it is 'addOperation' related issue (line-2), what will its solution then. How it is possible to become the operation (transferOperation) nil. Advance thanks for your help.

line-1:

```
_ = self.addTransferOperation(device: device, deviceIndex:index, dataTransferCategory:OMVitalDataTransferCategory.bloodPressure)
```

Line-2:

```
func addTransferOperation(device: ConnectedDevice, deviceIndex:Int, dataTransferCategory:OMVitalDataTransferCategory = OMVitalDataTransferCategory.all) -> ConnectivityTransferOperation {
    let transferOperation = ConnectivityTransferOperation()
    //            transferOperation.isUserNotify = device == sortedDeviceList.last ? notifyUser : false
    let connectedDevice = ConnectedDevice(value : device)
    transferOperation.device = ConnectedDevice(value : device)
    transferOperation.transferDataType = dataTransferCategory
    transferOperation.completionBlock = {
        LogManager.shared.addLog(logString: "completion of transfer operation",localName: connectedDevice.deviceLocalName, uuid: connectedDevice.uuid)
        // Remove first item
        if !self.pendingOperations.syncInProgress.isEmpty {
            self.pendingOperations.syncInProgress.removeAll(where: {$0 == transferOperation})
        }
        
        // Empty queue
        if self.pendingOperations.syncInProgress.isEmpty {
            // update autosync timer if Manual sync
            if (self.isManualSync) {
                self.updateSyncTimer()
            }
        }
        
        // Reset bluetooth state
        self.resetBluetoothState()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Set error from transfer operation and set flag to check if it happened in transfer operation
            let transferOperationDetails: [String : Any] = [ConnectivityConfiguration.error: transferOperation.error,
                                                     ConnectivityConfiguration.isTransferOperation:true]
            // post notification for stop data transfer with transfer error operation object
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dataTransferStop,
                                            object: transferOperationDetails)
        }
    }
    
    LogManager.shared.addLog(logString: "Add transfer operation for device \(device.displayName)",localName: connectedDevice.deviceLocalName, uuid: connectedDevice.uuid)
    // Add operation and start
    self.pendingOperations.syncInProgress.append(transferOperation)
    if deviceIndex > 0 {
        // add dependency
        transferOperation.addDependency(self.pendingOperations.syncInProgress[deviceIndex-1])
    }
    self.pendingOperations.syncQueue.addOperation(transferOperation)
    
    return transferOperation
}
```

Crash:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Foundation                     0x114ea8 ____addOperations_block_invoke.567 + 680
1  Foundation                     0x113858 __addOperations + 1288
2  GrandApp                      0x7bd3d8 ConnectivityManager.addTransferOperation(device:deviceIndex:dataTransferCategory:) + 2411 (ConnectivityManager.swift:2411)
3  GrandApp                      0x7bc3f0 ConnectivityManager.transferOperation(withDevices:notifyUser:isManualSync:) + 4313269232 (<compiler-generated>:4313269232)
4  GrandApp                      0x7a6770 ConnectivityManager.startTransferOperation(notifyUser:device:syncAllData:isBeaconFlow:) + 4313180016 (<compiler-generated>:4313180016)
5  GrandApp                      0x6c4aa4 closure #1 in DashboardViewController.refreshAction() + 1096 (DashboardViewController.swift:1096)
6  GrandApp                      0x7cc37c specialized ConnectivityManager.isSyncing(withStop:completion:) + 4313334652 (<compiler-generated>:4313334652)
7  GrandApp                      0x6c4218 DashboardViewController.refreshAction() + 4312252952 (<compiler-generated>:4312252952)
8  GrandApp                      0x6c4aec @objc DashboardViewController.refreshAction() + 4312255212 (<compiler-generated>:4312255212)
9  UIKitCore                      0x8be300 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
10 UIKitCore                      0x367424 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
11 UIKitCore                      0x367744 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
12 UIKitCore                      0x3667b0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 568
13 UIKitCore                      0x8f55c4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2108
14 UIKitCore                      0x8f67ec -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3140
15 UIKitCore                      0x8d685c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
16 UIKitCore                      0x99c9d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 1768
17 UIKitCore                      0x99f100 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4828
18 UIKitCore                      0x998330 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 15
19 CoreFoundation                 0xaaf1c CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 24
20 CoreFoundation                 0xaae9c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
21 CoreFoundation                 0xaa784 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
22 CoreFoundation                 0xa56c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
23 CoreFoundation                 0xa4fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
24 GraphicsServices               0xa79c GSEventRunModal + 104
25 UIKitCore                      0x8bcc38 UIApplicationMain + 212
26 GrandApp                      0x1db0c main + 19 (AppDelegate.swift:19)
27 libdyld.dylib                  0x18e0 start + 4
```

ConnectivityTransferOperation.swift

```
import UIKit
import OMConnectivityLibrary

/// Transfer operation for connectivity
class ConnectivityTransferOperation : ConnectivityOperation {
    
    override func main() {
        guard isCancelled == false else {
            finish(true)
            return
        }
        self.executing(true)
    }
    
    override func end() {
        // Super call
        super.end()
    }
}
```

ConnectivityOperation.swift

```
import UIKit
import OMConnectivityLibrary

class ConnectivityOperation: Operation {
    
    /// Making operation queue async
    override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        get {
            return  true
        }
    }
    
    private var _executing = false {
        willSet {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
        didSet {
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
    }
    
    private var _finished = false {
        willSet {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
        didSet {
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }
    
    override var isExecuting: Bool {
        return _executing
    }
    
    override var isFinished: Bool {
        return _finished
    }
    
    func executing(_ executing: Bool) {
        _executing = executing
    }
    
    func finish(_ finished: Bool) {
        _finished = finished
    }
    
    func end() {
        self.finish(true)
        self.executing(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log.

Comment: Can you explain more about this issue

Comment: Also it's possible solution

Comment: Which one is this line : connectivitymanager.swift:2411 ?

Comment: Yes, the issue is inside this function below. What do you think @ptit-xav

ConnectivityManager.swift:2411

Comment: I was asking if you could add something to which is the line 2411 of connectivityMabager.swift to see what is the instruction which fails and with which parameters .

Comment: You can follow Line-1 and Line-2. None of the parameter is nil in the Line-1. I think error is something like that given below. But I didn't know what is the exact reason for this.

1  Foundation                     0x113858 __addOperations + 1288

Comment: What happens in syncInProgress.append ? Is there any chance that opération get resetted there ?